# How to map keys on Linux like my Mac machine

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, macosx, copy-and-paste

On my Macbook, I use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> = SIGINT and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> = copy (as in copy/paste).
On my Ubuntu machine, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> = SIGINT and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> = copy depending on the context and that's awful, because it's the same keystroke.

Does anyone know of a good way to map keys on Ubuntu so that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> = copy and maybe <kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> = SIGINT?

Furthermore, in the Ubuntu terminal window, to copy/paste I have to use ctrl+shift+c /p which is annoying - I would rather just use ctrl+c / ctrl+p, and to issue a SIGINT, use a different keystroke.

note: the windows key is also known as the superkey:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key

Comment: Indeed it is easy enough to change the Ctrl+C key in the termnal to do copy instead, but then we would need to find a way to bind another key to SIGINT.

Comment: thanks @vanadium yeah I am wondering how to do it reliably

Comment: See my answer to bind another key to SIGINT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remap the "Copy" function in the terminal emulator to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in "Preferences" - "Shortcuts". That will override the tty terminal shortcut.

Options to change the tty terminal shortcuts are more limited. These shortcuts stem from older times, and only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> combinations may be supported. You can change the assignment of these keys with the `stty`.

To see all assignments, use the command

```
ssty -a
```

To change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> assignment which by default is to "intr", use the command

```
stty intr "^X"
```

Here, intr was remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

To automatically remap that key as soon as you start the terminal, add the command to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: so I guess the cmd key is not recognized, only the ctrl key

Comment: i think you have a typo - `stty` vs `stty`

Comment: yeah I have this output on my Mac: `cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
 eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
 min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
 stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;`  so it's just ctrl+c but on the mac machine itself I switched the mapping for ctrl and command keys. cmd+c is default for copy and ctrl-c is default for kill, but I switched the command and ctrl keys. the nice thing about mac is by default the cmd and ctrl keys are different.

Answer (score 1):

Will that be helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en?
The article is for 19.10 but it is the same from 18.04 at least.
You can modify existing mappings and create your custome writing a command you want.

Comment: Please include relevant information directly in your answer. Link only answers are not supported here. I do not believe that this will help the OP, though. Did you test?